# MySQL - Help joining two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have spent the last few days trying to join these tables, but my knowledge of MySQL is limited, and after searching around Google, I have struggled to find a similar problem to help solve mine.

Basically, I have 1 table that stores a list of IP addresses that have connected to my site and I select them as follows (playerIP is the ip as a string):

```
SELECT playerIP FROM playerLogin GROUP BY playerIP
```

I also have a table that stores country IP blocks, but they optimized in such a way so that to select the Country of an IP you do:

```
SELECT * FROM ipCountry WHERE ip < INET_ATON('127.0.0.1') ORDER BY ip DESC LIMIT 0, 1
```

Without the limit, it returns many rows, but its the first row that's the country for that IP.

Im trying to join these tables in such a way so that i have the original list of IP's from the first query, but having the country for that IP as well.

Any help appreciated,

Dave.

Edit:

As an example, my VPS is in france, on the IP '178.32.35.179' and the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM ipCountry WHERE ip < INET_ATON( '178.32.35.179' ) ORDER BY ip DESC LIMIT 0 , 5
```

Returns the 5 rows:
   ip country

```
 - 2988441600 ~ fr
 - 2988179456 ~ se
 - 2987917312 ~ de
 - 2987915264 ~ it
 - 2987913216 ~ dk
```

Where the first returned row is France

---

Edit 2:

Sample of the start of the ipCountry table:
ip ~ country

```
 - 0 ~ us
 - 16777216 ~ au
 - 16777472 ~ cn
 - 16778240 ~ au
 - 16779264 ~ cn
```

Comment: please specify how are made your tables

Comment: I got the country ip tables from http://www.ip2nation.com/

Answer (score 2):

You want to do this as a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT pl.playerIP,
       (select c.country
        from ipCountry c
        where ip < INET_ATON(pl.playerIP)
        order by ip desc
        limit 1
       ) as country
FROM playerLogin pl
GROUP BY playerIP;
```

EDIT:

See if this version works faster:

```
SELECT playerIP,
       (select c.country
        from ipCountry c
        where ip < theip
        order by ip desc
        limit 1
       ) as country
FROM (select distinct playerIP, INET_ATON(pl.playerIP) as theip
      from playerLogin pl
     ) pl;
```

Perhaps the `group by` resulted in the subquery being executed multiple times for each IP.

And I assume that you already have an index on `ipCountry(ip, Country)`.  Also, shouldn't it be `<=` rather than `<`?

EDIT II:

You can create a new table using the same `limit 1` trick:

```
select country, ip,
       (select min(ip)
        from ipcountry ipc2
        where ipc2.country <> ip.country and
              ipc2.ip > ip.country
       ) ipnext
from ipcountry ipc;
```

Put this in a table and build an index on `(ip, ipnext, country)`.

Edit (Grimrandomer) :

I had to use:

```
select country, ip,
   (select ip
    from ipcountry ipc2
    where ipc2.ip > ipc.ip
    ORDER BY ip LIMIT 0, 1
   ) ipnext
from ipcountry ipc ORDER BY ip
```

but this only takes 0.0012 seconds for all 60,742 rows :)

---

The write your query as:

```
SELECT pl.playerIP, ipc.country
FROM playerLogin pl join
     ipcountry ipc
     on pl.ipc >= ipc.ip and pl.ipc < ipc.ipnext
GROUP BY playerIP;
```

Actually, if players have lots of logins, it might be better to use the subquery:

```
SELECT pl.playerIP, ipc.country
FROM (selectd distinct playerIP
      from playerLogin pl
     ) pl join
     ipcountry ipc
     on pl.ipc >= ipc.ip and pl.ipc < ipc.ipnext
GROUP BY playerIP;
```

Comment: I have to use `order by ip DESC`  for this to work. But I have 3000+ IP's in my table, limiting this query 0,100 it takes 8.6138 seconds, how do you think i should go about optimizing this?

Comment: *Nobody* should want to do *anything* as a correlated subquery :-(

Comment: 100 Rows takes 8.7927 sec, so I don't think it has made to much of an improvement, it may be worth changing the ipCountry database to include an end ip so that I can do join on > low and <= high, what do you think?

Comment: @Grimrandomer . . . Yes, that would probably help a lot.

Comment: I have posted a sample of the database in edit2, because its 65000 rows, if you know of any way of adding that second range value in sql to each row, even if it takes a while to do, would be helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

It suppose to be something like

```
SELECT p1.playerIP, p2.Country FROM playerLogin p1
INNER JOIN ipCountry p2 ON p1.playerIP = p2.ip
```

UPDATE: Grimrandomer, thank you for additional info. Unfortunately I'm not familiar with INET_ATON function, but after reading this (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton) I think that the following might work for you:

```
SELECT p1.playerIP, p2.Country FROM playerLogin p1
INNER JOIN ipCountry p2 ON INET_ATON(p1.playerIP) = p2.ip
```

UPD 2: What about this:

```
SELECT p1.playerIP, p2.Country, MAX(p2.ip) FROM playerLogin p1
    LEFT JOIN ipCountry p2 ON INET_ATON(p1.playerIP) > p2.ip
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

Comment: Thankyou for your suggestion, however I cannot simply join p1.playerIP and p2.ip because player ip is a string, and ip is a number for the ip block, so the second query gets the first block with a smaller INET_ATON and limits the results to 1 :(

Comment: Could you please provide an example of what you call ip block? We can try to parse it

Comment: I edited my question with an example of the countryIP table, hope it helps :)

Comment: Looked at your update, that's the closest I managed to get myself, but continuing the example,  INET_ATON( '178.32.35.179' ) will return 2988450739, but the "block" for france is 2988441600, It needs to join on the first p2.ip thats below INET_ATON(p1.playerIP)

Comment: Try to play with INET_NTOA http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-ntoa on ipCountry.ip and see what it gives

Comment: Had a look at INET_NTOA, seems to convert the number format of ip into the text representation, but sadly, still wont be able to join the tables with it, as the table stores the start IP of the block.

Comment: Ok, lets look on following: SELECT CAST(INET_NTOA('2886471682') AS CHAR(10000) CHARACTER SET utf8). It returns the following string: '172.12.16.2'. I think this way you can convert ip blocks to ip addresses

Comment: The problem is not converting it to blocks, its that INET_ATON(p1.playerIP) is a number, but I need to link it to the first p2.ip that's a smaller number

Comment: Looked at your update, sadly due to the size of the database it crashed, Gordons answer seems to work wonders, but thanks very much for your time :)